# VS 2017 (15.7.3) comments not collapsing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, comments

After updating to 15.7.3 I noticed that a block of comments does not have a + sign in front of them allowing it to be collapsed.

Clean-rebuild or restart VS, still the same.

Is this a bug or a new feature introduced in this version ?
If a feature what is the setting to have the 'old' behavior ?

Comment: I suggest to post your problem here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/visual+studio+2017+version+15.7.3.html?filter=all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to later version and bug disappeared.